# iOS/Swift: Quick & dirty way to send a notification to another device?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to write a super-simple iOS app, just for personal use (i.e. it doesn't need to conform to any App Store stuff).  I want it to do the following. Assume it's installed on two devices, both of which I own/control.

On device 1, it has a button that, when pressed, will immediately cause a notification to pop up on device 2.

I'm fine with hardcoding specific apple IDs, device IDs, whatever; it's also fine if this only works when the two devices are on the same LAN/Wifi. all I want is for the above to work, in the easiest way possible, and preferably without needing anything to run on a server anywhere.

How simply can this be implemented? I've set up a whole push-notification system once before, but that required some server-side stuff. Hoping to be able to do this without any of that.

====

**Update**: realized I wasn't clear in the original post that I need the notification on Device 2 to pop up whether or not the app is currently open/running on that device.

Comment: Maybe Firebase Remote Config can help you:
you can get your data in FCM remote config (key-value) from the app
https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=ios, and you can modify your data whenever you want, and the app can fetch it.
https://www.raywenderlich.com/17323848-firebase-remote-config-tutorial-for-ios

Comment: Send sms to port is another way (the protocol will become SMS):
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsportmessage

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are searching for is multipeer connectivity framework.

> The Multipeer Connectivity framework supports the discovery of
> services provided by nearby devices and supports communicating with
> those services through message-based data, streaming data, and
> resources (such as files). In iOS, the framework uses infrastructure
> Wi-Fi networks, peer-to-peer Wi-Fi, and Bluetooth personal area
> networks for the underlying transport. In macOS and tvOS, it uses
> infrastructure Wi-Fi, peer-to-peer Wi-Fi, and Ethernet.
>
> source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity.

You can also check those tutorials:

https://www.ralfebert.com/ios-app-development/multipeer-connectivity/

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/networking/how-to-create-a-peer-to-peer-network-using-the-multipeer-connectivity-framework

Comment: Clarified the question a bit -- unless I'm misunderstanding it sounds like the multipeer connectivity framework requires the app to be open on both devices for the receiving device to get the message; in that case it won't work for this. Or is that not the case? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I think that app must be running in the foreground on both devices for multipeer connectivity. So in that case unfortunately I think it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Send sms to port is a way (the protocol will become SMS): https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsportmessage

and Maybe Firebase Remote Config can help you: you can get your data in FCM remote config (key-value) from the app :
https://www.raywenderlich.com/17323848-firebase-remote-config-tutorial-for-ios
https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/get-started?platform=ios
, and you can modify your data whenever you want, and the app can fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar requirements, and it seems like APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) is required for this because it's one of the only ways to 'activate' an application that is in the background.

As a result, then the question is how to make APNS as painless as possible? It seems like combining [Firebase Cloud Messaging (or FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) (to manage APNS / sending messages), and Firebase Functions (to help manage FCM server-side requirements) is one decent option.